# jQuery .get and .css setting background image

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-hover, jquery-get

I have several divs making up a single button on a menu. Using jQuery, I'm trying to update the divs to a hover background image, without using individual selectors.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(".menuitem div").on('hover', function () {
      $("div").get(1).css('background-image', 'url("img/header/leftHov.png");');
   });
});
```

When I run this code, I get "Object div has no method 'css'".
My HTML in case you were wondering looks something like this:

```
<div style="width:100px;" class="menuitem">
    <div style="background: url('img/header/leftReg.png');">
    <div style="background:url('img/header/midReg.png');background-repeat:repeat-x;">
    <a href="./about.php" class="menu">About </a>
    <div style="background:url('img/header/rightReg.png');">
</div>
```

Comment: you're approaching this incorrectly. inside the "on" function don't select all divs, just do $(this) to get the div selected by the ".menuitem div"

Comment: I can't just bind it to one div since I have several divs that need updated background images.

Comment: @J4G: It's `background-image`, just like you initially had, not `backgroundImage`.

Comment: $("div").get(1) means first div on the page...if that's what you want ok, but it feels wrong. What happens if you have to add a new div before that one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) will give you the DOM element, not the jQuery object. You should use [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) instead. However, since you are already binding the event to the `div` that you want, simply use `$(this)`:

```
$(this).css('background-image', 'url("img/header/leftHov.png")');
```

Comment: I can't just bind it to one div since I have several divs that need updated background images. Thanks for the .eq() tip though.

Comment: @J4G: So you basically want to change the background-image of all images to leftHov.png, midHov.png, and rightHov.png instead? Or just a single one?